# Image disappearing on scrolling in listview xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image: ListView Xamarin forms]

I have ListView in xamarin forms. On scrolling this Listview up and down this clock image appears and disappears inconsistently.

Even if i hardcode the visibility, the image is inconsistent.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="5" Padding="0,0,10,0">
                    <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="#455560" Text="{Binding DispenseTypeWithMachineCount}" WidthRequest="250"/>
                    <Image IsVisible="{Binding IsServiceInProgress}" Source="ic_progress.png" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>

<ListView x:Name="ListViewAccounts" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ExpandedGroups}" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}" IsGroupingEnabled="true" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource accountTemplateSelector}" GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource groupHeaderTemplate}">
            <ListView.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ListViewAccountItemTappedCommand                               Source={x:Reference ListViewAccounts}}" />
            </ListView.Behaviors>
            <x:Arguments>
                <ListViewCachingStrategy>RecycleElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
            </x:Argume
```

Comment: its probably because its taking time to load the image, check if the image size is huge. And use FFloading.Forms CachedImage with Cache=always if you want better performance on images

Comment: Tried using FFLoading...still image disappears on vigorous scrolling....

Comment: what's your XF version ?i could not  repeat your question,you could try to update XF.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT i am using XF 4.1... still the same issue...

Comment: is the clock img in your lsitview groupheader?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Nope.. if you see the image.. Vans Corp (1) is the Group Header below are the children

Comment: i think it maybe happened on Android,have you test on ios?

Answer (score 2):

I've also had previous problems with moving images, their behaviour is inconsistent. I've solved most of them by using vectorized icons wherever possible, instead of image files, and that seems to be suitable for your case as you're also using an icon.

I recomend using FFImageLoading (as recommended before) to load SVGs, it loads fast and caches them for future use. Do the following to replace your PNG reference to a SVG:

1. Install [FFImageLoading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading) and [FFImageLoading.Svg](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg/) into your project from the NuGet packages manager
2. Download [clock.svg](https://fontawesome.com/icons/clock?style=regular) from FontAwesome
3. Place the icon inside a folder in your project and set its Build Action to **Embedded resource**
4. Add the FFImageLoading reference to the top of your XAML:

```
    xmlns:ffsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
```

5. Replace your `Image` element inside the `DataTemplate` with the following:

```
    <ffsvg:SvgCachedImage IsVisible="{Binding IsServiceInProgress}" Source="resource://[PATH_TO_YOUR_SVG_INSIDE_NAMESPACE].clock.svg" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
```

Example:

```
    <ffsvg:SvgCachedImage IsVisible="{Binding IsServiceInProgress}" Source="resource://MyProject.Resources.clock.svg" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
```

SVGs are lighter to load, have a better resolution, and the flicker should be solved.

Another thing that could help is messing around with the List `CachingStrategy` property, as it defines the way elements in the List are cached and rendered. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance) for more info about ListView Performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change how list views recycle elements, I noticed you are implementing it but yours looks weird:

Types of strategies :

- `RetainElement   // the default value`
- `RecycleElement`
- `RecycleElementAndDataTemplate`

**ListView:**

```xml
<ListView
    x:Name="ListViewAccounts"
    Margin="0,0,0,0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ExpandedGroups}"
    GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}"
    IsGroupingEnabled="true"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource accountTemplateSelector}"
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
    GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource groupHeaderTemplate}">
    <ListView.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="ItemTapped"
            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ListViewAccountItemTappedCommand,  Source={x:Reference ListViewAccounts}}" />
    </ListView.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```